# How can I pass an async from page 1 to page 2, and execute the function in page 2 but display results on page 1?

Tags: flutter, dart, data-structures

I'm accessing a menu item which redirects me to a second page like so:

```
void handleClick(String value) {
switch (value) {
  case 'Circles':
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => new CircleMaker()));
    break;
```

On this second page, I have three TextFormFields as a StatefulWidget. They look like this:

```
new Container(
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.colorBurn),
                    child: TextFormField(
                        controller: longitudeController,
                        cursorColor: Colors.white,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'longitude',
                        ))),
```

Lastly, I have this button on page 2:

```
                      FloatingActionButton(
                        child: Icon(Icons.lens),
                        backgroundColor: isPressed ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
                        onPressed: () {
                          _makeCircles();
                    setState(() => isPressed = !isPressed);
                        },
                      )])
                ]),
          )]));

  }
}
```

The _makeCircles(); function is not defined/available in the page 2 build. But it's defined/available on page 1 and works perfectly. This is the function:

```
  Set<Circle> circles;
  Future<void> _makeCircles() async {
    setState(() {
      //work
      ]);
    });
  }
```

How can I grab this async function which is available on page 1, use it on page 2, and then be sent back to page 1 (which is a google map). To say this in another way, I want to enter my TextFormFields on page 2 and use them to plot a circle on page 1. Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function sendData in page2

```
sendData() async {
//Code to get location using Geolocator package.

return position;

}

In your page1,

Access sendData() function of page2 inside page1, to get your data.
```

Comment: Sorry, does sendData() async { go in void main for page 2 or somewhere else?

Comment: No not in main(), it's a separate func.

Comment: This didn't work. I think it's more complicated than that.